# How to put escape sequence in Objective C?

Tags: objective-c, cocoa-touch, nsstring

I have this small code:

```
NSString *size = [LabelNewContent stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString:@"return     Math.max(
document.body.scrollHeight, document.documentElement.scrollHeight,
document.body.offsetHeight, document.documentElement.offsetHeight,
document.body.clientHeight, document.documentElement.clientHeight
);"];
```

the problem is xcode doesnt recognize the parentheses and commas as a whole string.

Answer (score -2, accepted):

Replace you code by

```
NSString *size = [LabelNewContent stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString:@"return %f",Math.max(
                      document.body.scrollHeight, document.documentElement.scrollHeight,
                      document.body.offsetHeight, document.documentElement.offsetHeight,
                      document.body.clientHeight, document.documentElement.clientHeight
                      )];
```

hope it will help you.

Comment: This is incorrect. `Math.max()`, `document.body.etc`, and `document.documentElement.etc` are all JavaScript, and thus should be inside the string. [Inder Kumar Rathore’s answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/18442812/255489) is the correct one.

Answer (score 8):

Use `\` to make it multi line string

```
NSString *size = [LabelNewContent stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString:@"return     Math.max(\
document.body.scrollHeight, document.documentElement.scrollHeight,\
document.body.offsetHeight, document.documentElement.offsetHeight,\
document.body.clientHeight, document.documentElement.clientHeight\
);"];
```

Comment: Reason: You can't wrap a string literal over multiple lines without escaping the carriage returns.

Answer (score 0):

```
NSString *size = [LabelNewContent stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString:@"return     Math.max/(document.body.scrollHeight, document.documentElement.scrollHeight,document.body.offsetHeight, document.documentElement.offsetHeight,   document.body.clientHeight, document.documentElement.clientHeight);"];
```

try above thing